# How to align items HStack to VStack SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to swiftui, even though I tried all the ways, I can't get any reaction.

How to align everything like in the picture? (I've tried everything I know)

```
   ForEach(viewModel.setupList, id:\.self){ item in
        ZStack{
            Color.colorDark
            
            HStack{
                //TO-DO: get photo
                Image("icon_homeFeedImage")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth*0.2, height: UIScreen.screenHeight*0.12)
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    .padding()
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text(item.setupHeader)
                        .foregroundColor(.colorLight)
                        .font(.fontBoldDescription)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                    HStack{
                        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 10) {
                            Image("icon_mapPin")
                            Text(item.setupLocation)
                                .foregroundColor(.colorGrey1)
                                .font(.fontMiniButton)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Button {
                            
                        } label: {
                            Text(Localizable.view)
                                .foregroundColor(.colorHellium)
                                .font(.fontButton)
                        }.frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth * 0.23, height: UIScreen.screenHeight*0.05 )
                            .background(Color.colorGrey2)
                            .cornerRadius(16)
                            .padding(.bottom,12)
                    }.padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }
        }.frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth * 0.9, height: UIScreen.screenWidth * 0.35)
            .cornerRadius(16)
    }[enter image description here][1]
```

my design:

[image: my design]

desired design:

[image: desired design]

---

Comment: on inner HStack replace `.padding(.horizontal)`with `.padding(.trailing)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your full code, so I could not run your app.

However, here is a solution, try replicate my sample view with your own image, size, and resource. Code is below the image:
[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

let heightImage = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.1

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.black.opacity(0.7).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        VStack {
            Text("Favorite")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding(.bottom)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            ForEach(0...3, id: \.self) { _ in
                ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .fill(.black.opacity(0.5))
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.15)
                    HStack {
                        Image("swift")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: heightImage, height:  heightImage)
                            .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
                        VStack {
                            Text("Helium Setups for Nilufer Area")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .lineLimit(1)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center )
                            HStack {
                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName: "location.north.circle.fill")
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    
                                    Text("Busa, TR")
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                }
                                Spacer()
                                Button {
                                    
                                } label: {
                                    Text("View")
                                        .padding()
                                        .background(.black.opacity(0.7))
                                        .foregroundColor(.teal)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                        .font(.subheadline)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                            
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9)
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```